# Few slot connection in cycle

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I create few rows. Each row containt checkbox and combobox. I want chechbox to enable\disaple combobox. But it always enable\disable last combobox in list if I bind slots this way. How I can make each checkbox work with next combobox? I'm new to Qt\PySide. Here is simplefied code:

```
       for i, feature_name in zip(xrange(data_set.n_features), data_set.feature_names):
        rowLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        featureLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        active_checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        input = QtGui.QSpinBox()
        self.feature_inputs.append(input)
        def abc(state):
            self.feature_inputs[i].setEnabled(state == Qt.Checked)
        active_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(abc)
        rowLayout.addWidget(active_checkbox)
        rowLayout.addWidget(input)
        rowLayout.addWidget(featureLabel)
        self.ui.features_layout.addLayout(rowLayout)
```

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend not using input as a variable; input() is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: It's hard to choose which asnwer to accept. Both have good ideasm but @JustinPeel explain me problem with scopes so I'll use his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue more with scope in Python than with PySide. The variable i is defined in a scope outside of the abc function. That same variable is being used for each of your abc functions. The variable ends up having the value of the last time through the loop which is why the checkboxes always toggle the last spinbox. You need something like the following to ensure that a separate index variable is created for each of your abc functions:

```
def abcmaker(ind):
    def abc(state):
        self.feature_inputs[ind].setEnabled(state == Qt.Checked)
    return abc
active_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(abcmaker(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        for x in xrange(3):
            layout.addLayout(CheckComboGroup())

class CheckComboGroup(QHBoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckComboGroup, self).__init__(parent)

        self.checkBox = QCheckBox()
        self.checkBox.clicked.connect(self.handleComboBox)

        self.comboBox = QComboBox()

        self.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.addWidget(self.comboBox)

    def handleComboBox(self):
        self.comboBox.setDisabled(self.comboBox.isEnabled())

app = QApplication([])
main = Main()
main.show()
app.exec_()
```